# How to Implement Zoom Magnifier in MuPDF

Tags: android, pdf, mupdf

I have recently included `MuPDF` in my project for loading PDF files, I want to Implement  magnifier feature for the PDF.

I have looked over the documentation I could not find anyway to send a rect of X  to `MuPDF` and respond with bitmap.

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fz_new_pixmap_with_bbox`. The [simple example](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=blob;f=docs/examples/example.c) included in the package should give you a starting point.

Comment: This link is broken